# Pandas: Run a set of codes for multiple parameters with multiple levels of each parameter (output is a dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

Lets say we have a set of codes as given below. Currently, we have two parameters whose value are initialized by user input. The output here is a dataframe.

What we want?

Use a function, to create a dataframe with all combinations of X and Y. Lets say X and Y has 4 input values each. Then

Join the output dataframe, **df** for each combination to get the desired output dataframe.

```
X= float(input("Enter the value of X: "))
Y = float(input("Enter the value of Y: "))
A= X*Y
B=X*(Y^2)
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": X, "Y": Y, "A": A, "B": B})
```

**Desired output**

```
X   Y   A   B
1   2   2   4
1   4   4   16
1   6   6   36
1   8   8   64
2   2   4   8
2   4   8   32
2   6   12  72
2   8   16  128
3   2   6   12
3   4   12  48
3   6   18  108
3   8   24  192
4   2   8   16
4   4   16  64
4   6   24  144
4   8   32  256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
def so_help():
    x = input('Please enter all X values separated by a comma(,)')
    y = input('Please enter all Y values separated by a comma(,)')
    #In case anyone gets comma happy
    x = x.strip(',')
    y = y.strip(',')
    x_list = x.split(',')
    y_list = y.split(',')
    
    df_x = pd.DataFrame({'X' : x_list})
    df_y = pd.DataFrame({'Y' : y_list})
    df_cross = pd.merge(df_x, df_y, how = 'cross')
    
    df_cross['X'] = df_cross['X'].astype(int)
    df_cross['Y'] = df_cross['Y'].astype(int)
    df_cross['A'] = df_cross['X'].mul(df_cross['Y'])
    df_cross['B'] = df_cross['X'].mul(df_cross['Y'].pow(2))
    return df_cross
    
so_help()
```

Comment: The out put I got is "'Please input the same length for X and Y'"

Comment: Please enter all X values separated by a comma(,)100,20,9
Please enter all Y values separated by a comma(,)9,9,9
'Please input the same length for X and Y'

Comment: I updated the code that should get you around that problem. However, I did not build it to be resilient to all scenarios only this one that I could think of off the top of my head.

Comment: But why X and Y has to be of same length??

Comment: Did you try taking it out and seeing what happens when you don't have the same number of items in the lists?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work. Its throwing an error with split function

Comment: What did you try, can you give me an example like in the previous comment?

Comment: Please enter all X values separated by a comma(,)2,3
Please enter all Y values separated by a comma(,)1,9,10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [40], in <cell line: 20>()
     17     df['B'] = df['X'].mul(df['Y'].pow(2))
     18     return df

Comment: ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245500/discussion-between-archangelpwn-and-vp-050).